# Подключение GLEW к Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, opengl

Пытаюсь подключить GLEW к Visual Studio Express 2013.

Что я сделал:

В настройках указал пути к папкам с дополнительными заголовочными файлами (сделал папку include и указал путь в настройках проекта) и библиотекам (сделал папку lib и тоже указал путь).

Положил `C:\Users\%User%\Desktop\glew-1.12.0-win32\glew-1.12.0\bin\Release\Win32\glew32` в `%Папка с проектом%\Debug`. Также в свойствах проекта у меня стоит "Все конфигурации". Сделал это по инструкции установки GLFW (когда устанавливал GLFW, то в инструкции нужно было сделать этот шаг).

`C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\glew-1.12.0-win32\glew-1.12.0\include\GL` все файлы в `%Папка с проектом%\%Папка с названием проекта%\include`.

`C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\glew-1.12.0-win32\glew-1.12.0\lib\Release\Win32` все *lib'ы* в `%Папка с проектом%\%Папка с названием проекта%\lib`.

Также у меня установлен GLFW, но он работает.

Ошибки с GLEW (вставил пример кода с использованием GLFW и GLEW):

Comment: Вот видиоурок на эту тему, правда он на украинском, и для visual studio 2010 (x32) но можэт сработать. там под видео можна скачать скомпилированые библиотеки, а звук можэте одключить, там не очень важно наверно. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nZteX9rIhD0&t=8s Следующие будет понятно при просмотре
Там описана папка Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0 только вместо 10.0 будет ваша версия, и в зависимости от розрядности системы и визуалки нужная папка может лижать в одной из двух папок програм файлов.

Answer (score 1):

Если ошибка 0xc0000007b , то попробуй скомпилировать в режиме Release, а не Debug :
http://www.cyberforum.ru/visual-cpp/thread845225.html

Если это сработает, то можно в Debug исправить опцию на Project -> Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library : Multi-threaded DLL (/MD) . После этого у меня заработал и Debug режим. Только сперва удали созданные папки Debug в папке проекта и построй приложения заново уже с новыми настройками.

Answer (score 0):

Для подключения GLEW(x64) нужно сделать следующее:

glew32.lib, glew32s.lib положить сюда:
C:\Program Files (x86)\%VS FOLDER%\VC\lib\amd64

glew.h, glxew.h, wglew.h положить сюда:
C:\Program Files (x86)\%VS FOLDER%\VC\include\GL

glew32.dll положить сюда:
C:\Windows\System32

Далее выбрать нужный проект, нажать правой кнопкой мышки, выбрать Properties-> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Depencecies. В текстовое окно вписать glew32.lib.

Важно! Конфигурация солюшена должна быть x64.